# What Is Wrong With My Coding

Tags: java, android

When I run the analize it on comes back with one error in the manafest android name = is not public
but when i build it says built with no error but when i run it on my emu and my tablet it crashes i can not figure this out please help. This is my code with names omitted.

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.xxxx.xxxx.app.MainActivity"
android:background="@drawable/appbackground">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/facebook"
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:background="@drawable/facebook"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:gravity="end"
    android:width="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button3" />

 <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/dealer"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:background="@drawable/dealer"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button4" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/map"
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="@drawable/google_navigation"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="29dp" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/about"
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="@drawable/about"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/pthdh"
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="@drawable/pthdh" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/rpe"
    android:id="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="@drawable/rpebutton" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/call"
    android:id="@+id/button7"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="@drawable/callus"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/contact"
    android:id="@+id/button8"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="@drawable/contact"
    android:layout_marginBottom="31dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button7"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextClock
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textClock"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:background="#ff5300"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textIsSelectable="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button8"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button8"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button8"
    android:layout_marginBottom="34dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.xxxx.xxxx.app;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;



class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        Button button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        Button button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        Button button5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
        Button button6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
        Button button7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);
        Button button8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button8);

        button1.setOnClickListener(this);
        button2.setOnClickListener(this);
        button3.setOnClickListener(this);
        button4.setOnClickListener(this);
        button5.setOnClickListener(this);
        button6.setOnClickListener(this);
        button7.setOnClickListener(this);
        button8.setOnClickListener(this);

    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch(v.getId()){
            case R.id.button1:
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setClassName("com.facebook.katana",
                        "com.facebook.katana.ProfileTabHostActivity");
                Long uid = new Long("xxxx");
                intent.putExtra("extra_user_id", uid);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            case R.id.button2:
                intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse
                        ("http://www.xxxx.com"));
                startActivity(intent);

                break;
            case R.id.button3:
                Uri location = Uri.parse("geo:xx.xxx7629,-xx.xxxx584?z=14");
                new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, location);

                break;
            case R.id.button4:
                intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse
                        ("http://www.xxxx.com/default.asp?page=info"));
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            case R.id.button5:
                intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse
                        ("http://www.xxxx.com/"));
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            case R.id.button6:
                intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse
                        ("https://members.xxxx.com/"));
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            case R.id.button7:
                Intent dial = new Intent();
                dial.setAction("android.intent.action.DIAL");
                dial.setData(Uri.parse("tel:xxxx"));
                startActivity(dial);
                break;
            case R.id.button8:
                intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse
                        ("http://www.xxxx.com/default.asp?page=xcontact"));
                startActivity(intent);
                break;

            default:
                Log.d(getApplication().getPackageName(), "Button click error!");
                break;
        }
    }



    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    return id == R.id.action_settings || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
```

AndroidManifest xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.xxxx.xxxx.app" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>


<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
<activity
    android:name="com.xxxx.xxxx.app.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"/>


</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: and please post your stacktrace/logcat.

Comment: ill post those as soon as i can i'm headed out for the weekend will post monday

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put "public" before "class":

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
```

Comment: seriously that was all that was jacking me up

Comment: it still crashes as soon as click on it it goes to unfortunately XXXX has stopped

Comment: Ok, please post your stacktrace/logcat. If you do, we won't have to read through your code. It should state pretty clearly what the problem is.

Comment: ok i will when i get back Monday i cant get to the computer with the info till then but thank you on the manifest issue that fixed right away cant beleave i missed that

Comment: It might be another issue. Accept this answer (or not) and post a new question in that case. Good luck.

Comment: ok i got in remotely and got it to launch in the emu without crashing the only error i get is on the facebook but i cant post it all here not enough characters

Comment: thank you a lot for the help have not built an app with this much function before so it is killing me